# Handle Data.init for local files without Segmentation fault

Tags: linux, swift

Running Swift 3.0.2 on Linux, imageData will throw Segmentation fault if image file is not found on the local drive (deleted or removed), how to handle this error?

```
let url:URL? = URL(fileURLWithPath: "files/photo.jpg")


do {
    if let k = url {
    let imageData: Data = try? Data.init(contentsOf: k)
    }
}catch{
print("error or missing")
}
```

Comment: What's the stacktrace? Where is it actually crashing? Are you using the latest Swift? As a general rule, you can't handle a segfault; this indicates a bug somewhere. Make sure to compare to `Data(contentsOfFile:)` to avoid creating the extra `URL` (not because the `URL` is wrong; just to narrow down the bug).

Comment: How about if using FileManager to check if file is exist? I manage to solve by checking for existing file before reading data. It's just that if file is missing, it will crash, probably a bug.